# How to communicate with HiveServer2 running NONE authentication

Tags: hive, thrift, sasl, thrift-protocol

I'm trying to communicate with HiveServer2 via ruby TCPSocket. As per Thrift SASL spec, I send START message and then plain auth information.
Server returns COMPLETE status with an empty payload. It should return challenge as a payload but an empty string.

```
START    = 0x01
OK       = 0x02
COMPLETE = 0x05

auth = 'PLAIN'
header = [START, auth.length].pack('cl>')

auth_string = ['anonymous'].pack('u')
auth_message = "[LOGIN] \u0000 #{auth_string} \u0000 #{auth_string}"
auth_header = [OK, auth_message.length].pack('cl>')

socket = TCPSocket.new localhost, 10000
socket.write header + auth
socket.write auth_header + auth_message

socket.read(5).unpack('cl>')
=> [5,0]
```

HiveServer2 returns 5 status that is COMPLETE.
No further communication is possible via this socket as the server returns nothing anymore.

I suspect auth_message constructed in a wrong way or something else is wrong.

Can anyone suggest the way HiveServer2 will understand my requests?

Any help will be appreciated.

UPD: [Thrift SASL spec](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/doc/thrift-sasl-spec.txt)

UPD2: Solved! STARTTLS block should look like following below:

```
START    = 0x01
OK       = 0x02
COMPLETE = 0x05

auth = 'PLAIN'
header = [START, auth.length].pack('cl>')
auth_message = "[ANONYMOUS]\u0000anonymous\u0000anonymous"
auth_header = [OK, auth_message.length].pack('cl>')

socket = TCPSocket.new localhost, 10000
socket.write header + auth
socket.write auth_header + auth_message
socket.read(5).unpack('cl>')
=> [5,0]
```

After COMPLETE status received from the server, I can use TCLIService::Client to communicate with the HiveServer2. Only one thing to notice:

> All writes to the underlying transport must be prefixed by the 4-byte length of the payload data, followed by the payload. All reads from this transport
>   should read the 4-byte length word, then read the full quantity of bytes
>   specified by this length word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use thrift gem and consider https://github.com/dallasmarlow/hiveserver2 instead of Ruby sockets.

Comment: Already tried, connection hangs with thrift/hiveserver2 gem since server expects to receive 'START' message. So I'm implementing my own gem that will support SASL mechanism.

Comment: The problem is solved! Moreover, there was no any problem :) Status 5 COMPLETE with an empty challenge is OK for NONE auth type. The final code for STARTTLS is in the originating post